# What do you call a table that is unstable?

Tags: word-request

Let's say there is a table or a chair for that matter, which has one of its legs broken a bit at bottom, because of that it is unstable and every time you lean on it wobbles due to lack of balance.

Describing it as unstable or unsteady seems very general, is there any word precisely for this?

Comment: Not to mention that “an unstable table” sound like there’s an echo in here in here.

Comment: An uns-table......

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think you've got the right word in your question--"wobbly" would be the term I'd use.  I just googled it and apparently there's even a website called [wobblytables.com](http://www.wobblytables.com/).  I can't tell if they're serious or not to be honest, but I think the term applies regardless!

Comment: Absolutely - and [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a+wobbly+table%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are over 5000 *written* instances of *"a wobbly table"* in Google Books to prove it's a well-used term.

Comment: You might also say that the table _rocks from side to side_.

Answer (score 4):

Rickety is the first word that comes to my mind, but also: rocky, wobbly, shaky, unsteady, jiggly, quaky, quavery, trembly, teetery, tottery.

Answer (score 3):

"Wonky" is a term I like to use in that situation. I think it's British in origin. It's got a tinge of humor as well, as opposed to the more precise words already offered.